# MaterialApp as ancestor of MediaQuery widget. But how?

Tags: flutter, media-queries, flutter-web

I am trying to make three different layouts according to the width of the window/screen. I get the error *"No MediaQuery widget ancestor found."* Since there are  a lot of examples where people had problems with MediaQuery widget ancestry, I figured, I have to give the MediaQuery widget a MaterialApp as an ancestor. But I can't wrap my head around it, how I can achieve that? Can anybody help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    if (screenSize.width < 600) {
      return lay1();
    } else if (screenSize.width < 800) {
      return lay2();
    } else {
      return lay3();
    }
  }
}

Widget lay1() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
  );
}

Widget lay2() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  );
}

Widget lay3() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.orangeAccent,
  );
}
```

Comment: Your MyApp isn't a MaterialApp. You need to return a MaterialApp to the run() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your `MyApp` widget in a `MaterialApp` widget like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

The `MediaQuery` instance is provided by `MaterialApp`. This is why you need to call `MediaQuery.of(context)` when getting the current instance of `MediaQuery`, and from there extracting the size of the view